# android filter listview works only for the first search

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter, searchview

i am been trying to figure what seems to be the issue, but can get my head round it, basically i am filtering my listview which uses custom adapter that has images and text. its works first time e.g. when the activity runs for the first time it has all the data and when i type something in the search box it filters it. but then from there if i now enter something else it doesn print anything and the array is empty which hold the data. any suggestion would be appreciated.

**filter code fragment**

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                data= (List<Data>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<Item> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<Item>();

                // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    Item dataNames = data.get(i);
                    if (dataNames.title.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {
                        FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                    }

                }

                results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
```

**activity code fragment**

```
 text =(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchData);

        text.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try returning false in onQueryTextChange() method.

Comment: problem still remains, filters the first time and empty array from there